# Issue Updating/Inserting a <script> Tag using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to Update/Insert a New  Tag using JQuery/AJAX. The URL found in the Script Tag is one from another Domain (Web Server), over which I have no control. The results provided by the Web Server are returned in an iframe (again, I have no control over the format of the response).

I have tried the following two solutions (Please note that the Click Button is only used for testing purposes).

First Solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var NewScript = document.createElement('script');
        NewScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        NewScript.src = 'http://www.contactedurl.com/query&callback=?';
        $("#TDiv").append(NewScript);
    });
});
```

Second Solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var NewScript = document.createElement('script');
        NewScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        NewScript.src = 'http://www.contactedurl.com/query&callback=?';
        var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        script.parentNode.insertBefore(NewScript, script);
    });
});
```

Both of these solutions generate the following warning message, and thus no update is performed:

> A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.

I understand the reason why this message is generated, and why no update is executed, but I wasn’t able to find any work around to this limitation, or an alternative solution.

I was wondering if anyone would know of an alternate solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you simply can't do it the way you're doing it. you'll have to include the script normally.

```
<div>
    <script src="http://www.contactedurl.com/query&callback=?"></script>
</div>
```

or with `document.write` (though it's pretty pointless to do it this way):

```
<div>
    <script>
      document.write("<scr"+"ipt src='http://www.contactedurl.com/query&callback=?'></scr"+"ipt>");
    </script>
</div>
```

where `<div>...</div>` is where you want the output to be.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thank you for your time and answer. After experimenting several solutions and doing some reading, I had concluded that I wasn’t moving in the right direction, as you have confirmed. Nevertheless, I would think that there should be an alternate way of dynamically changing the source url in a script Tag, no?

Comment: The problem isn't changing the url, the problem is what the script is doing. document.write() will completely replace your document if it is executed after the document is closed (which happens when the document is *"ready"*. that is why it must be executed synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a Ajax shorthand for that called `$.getScript()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/